# QResource::registerResource fails on Mac version

Tags: macos, qt

I have the following code that is working fine in my qt program (windows version):

```
if( false == QResource::registerResource( "data.rcc" ) )
{
//.... Error message
}
```

file is always found, application continues...

i started porting my application from Windows to Mac, while i was waiting for my mac computer to arrive, i used virtualbox with Mac image,
and it worked fine too, however now that i'm using a Mac computer, the same code always fails, it seems that the rcc file is never found, it needs
some kind of path that i still didn't sorted out, i tried many different paths but nothing.
Sorry, but y'm totally newbie on Mac and still don't understand some basic things like this file paths stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are registering a "relative path" for the resource. You'll need to check [QDir::searchPaths()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#searchPaths) to see where it is looking for resources. On Mac OS X, you may need to copy the file into the application bundle.